# Access excel data without opening it in application

Tags: excel

I am looking for a very fast way to process excel files stored on a network location. I need to check certain values in the excel files but my standard method of opening workbook, look for what I need and close is taking way to long for this huge pile of excel files.

Are there other method to access excel content without having to open them?

I have read about EPplus, but are there others?

Answer (score 0):

Using the ExecuteExcel4Macro command in VBA you can access data in excel files without opening the file itself. The downside is that you have to know the specific range you are looking for but it sounds like this may be the case for you.

For instance:

```
Private Function GetCellFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, wbName As String, wsName As String, _
                                       rowref As Long, colref As Long) As Variant
'Fetches the value of a single cell in a closed workbook
Dim val As String
    GetCellFromClosedFile = "" 'Clears old value
    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "" Then wbPath = wbPath & "" 'Clears path string
    If Dir(wbPath & "" & wbName) = "" Then Exit Function 'If no new path exit
    'Returns single cell - can only return a single cell - use ADO to get a range
    val = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & _
          Range(Cells(rowref, colref), Cells(rowref, colref)).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
    On Error Resume Next
    GetCellFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(val)
End Function
```